# Find where three separate DataFrames overlap and create a new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have three separate DataFrames. Each DataFrame has the same columns - `['Email', 'Rating']`. There are duplicate row values in all three DataFrames for the column `Email`. I'm trying to find those emails that appear in all three DataFrames and then create a new DataFrame based off those rows. So far I have I had all three DataFrames saved to a list like this `dfs = [df1, df2, df3]`, and then concatenated them together using `df = pd.concat(dfs)`. I tried using groupby from here but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: can you show us a code?

Comment: It's a 2 column by about 50 row DataFrame for each DataFrame. The DataFrames were created using pandas.read_csv. I can't show the actual DataFrame as it contains actual people's emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do a merge. Similar to a join in sql you can do an inner merge and treat the email like a foreign key. Here is the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html
It would look something like this:

```
in_common = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Email'], how='inner')
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try using .isin from pandas, e.g:

```
df[df['Email'].isin(df2['Email'])]
```

This would retrieve row entries where the values for the column email are the same in the two dataframes.

Another idea is maybe try an inner merge.

Goodluck, post code next time.